# How to map an audio file with Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my models page, Help me to add a mp3 File format in models and how can i play that mp3 on web page.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + '-' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
   album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.song_title
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `FileField` django type:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='musics/')
```

Then in your template:

```
<audio src="{{ song.file.url }}" autoplay></audio>
```

Comment: Note that the code provided in the answer won't show the actual player and will just play the audio in the background (may depend on the browser). 
In case you need to show a default player you can use the following html code: `<audio src="{{ song.file.url }}" controls></audio>`